# Transposing Images in R - Matrix transformation mirrors image

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I'm casting to a matrix. Every row represents an image in white, gray, and black colors.
[image]
The image corresponds to the number 5. I'm wondering what I am missing that the number 5 appears mirrored?

```
plotimage <- function(df,n, imageTitle) {
  convertedImage <- df
  matrx <- matrix(unlist(convertedImage[n,1:784]), byrow = T, nrow=28)
  image(col = gray(0:255/255), z = matrx)
}

plotimage(image5, 1600,"Image of 5")
```

**Output I want**

Number 5 not mirrored.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the (unusual) way `image` works:

> Notice that image interprets the z matrix as a table of f(x[i], y[j])
>   values, so that the x axis corresponds to row number and the y axis to
>   column number, with column 1 at the bottom, i.e. a 90 degree
>   counter-clockwise rotation of the conventional printed layout of a
>   matrix.

That's how your `matrx` is interpreted. Hence, writing

```
image(col = gray(0:255/255), z = matrx[nrow(matrx):1, ])
```

should fix it.